# Augmented Reality: superimpose texture over real objects. Is it possible?

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality

Please bear with me as English is not my first language but I will try to explain my question as clearly as I can.

Let's say I have made a 3D scan of a real table, exported it into a ThreeJS scene and created some texture around it.

I would like to view the real object through the camera of a phone, tablet (or any device you might find suitable for the task) and be able to superimpose the texture on the object in the camera view.

The AR app that I intend to develop should be able to detect the real object, the view angle, distance and be able resize the texture on the fly before being applied to the object on camera.

The question I am asking is: it possible to achieve this? If yes, I would like to know which technologies and development tools should I consider and explore. Have you done something similar in the past? I am trying to avoid to go on a path that will end up in a dead end and tears.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js is for a web application, as far as I know there´s not any way to mix a tracking like OpenCV script with Three.js
If you want a Mobile SDK capable of what you say, I suggest Vuforia + Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of technologies depends on the platform where you intend to run this application.

If we're talking mobile applications then you should check out ARKit (iOS) or ARCore (Android), and consider developing a native application instead of relying on JavaScript. The precision and performance of these native libraries is far better than what you'd achieve on your own or in a JavaScript application. This is not something Three.js won't do for you.